# for loop in where clause

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to calculate value through LINQ with two conditions, one of which happens to contain a foreach loop.

I've a list of integers statusList (stores StatCatId)

And based on the values in this list I want to add a where condition in my LINQ statement.

```
 var sListings = (from l in _colMgr.Listings.Values.AsEnumerable()
                                 where (l.SystemPrice ?? 0) > 0 &&
 // Need to add condition like foreach(s in statusList) if l.StatCatId == s
                                 select l).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yet another way with `join clause`

```
var sListings = 
(
    from l in _colMgr.Listings.Values.AsEnumerable()
    join s in statusList on l.StatCatId equals s
    where (l.SystemPrice ?? 0) > 0
    select l
).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

You might be looking for the `Contains` method:

```
var sListings = 
(
    from l in _colMgr.Listings.Values.AsEnumerable()
    where (l.SystemPrice ?? 0) > 0
       && statusList.Contains(l.StatCatId)
    select l
).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity of your calculation, you might use Contains, SelectMany, Sum, etc. , or plug in your own Func into your LINQ call.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = new List<DataPoint>
                   {
                       new DataPoint(){Condition = true, Value = 0, Values = new List<int>{1,2,3}},
                       new DataPoint(){Condition = false, Value = 10, Values = new List<int>{}},
                       new DataPoint(){Condition = true, Value = 0, Values = new List<int>{4,5}},
                       new DataPoint(){Condition = false, Value = 20, Values = new List<int>{}}
                   };
        var sum = data.Sum(s=>s.Condition?s.Values.Sum():s.Value);
    }
}

internal class DataPoint
{
    public bool Condition { get; set; }

    public int  Value { get; set; }

    public List<int> Values { get; set; }
}
```

or with an Func<>

```
Func<DataPoint, int> func = point => point.Condition ? point.Values.Sum() : point.Value;
var sum = data.Sum(s => func(s));
```

or if Func needs multiple steps:

```
        Func<DataPoint, int> func = point =>
        {
            var retValue = point.Condition ? point.Values.Sum() : point.Value;
            return retValue;
        };
        var sum = data.Sum(s => func(s));
```